# Получение активной радиокнопки PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, radiobutton

У меня есть группа `radioButton`, которые определяют куда записывать данные: в **А** или в **Б**, после нажатия на кнопку `Добавить`.

Как мне при нажатию на `pushbutton` получить активную радиокнопку из группы?

```
 def win_start(self):
    self.ui.show()

    self.r_btns_group_woman = QButtonGroup()
    self.r_btns_group_woman.addButton(self.ui.r_btn_woman_A)
    self.r_btns_group_woman.addButton(self.ui.r_btn_woman_B)
    self.ui.r_btn_woman_A.setChecked(True)

 def btn_events_listener(self):
    self.ui.btn_add_woman.clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_woman())

def add_woman(self):
    if self.ui.self.ui.r_btn_woman_A.isEnabled():
        print("A")
    else:
        print("B")
```

Если кому-то понадобится, прикрепляю скриншот

[image: Скриншот GUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Используйте `isChecked()`, чтобы узнать, выбрана ли конкретная кнопка.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.addItems(["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5",]);
        
        self.r_btn_woman_A = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("A")
        self.r_btn_woman_A.setChecked(True)
        self.r_btn_woman_B = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("B")
        
        self.btn_add_woman = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Добавить")
        self.btn_add_woman.clicked.connect(self.add_woman)
        
        self.r_btns_group_woman = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.r_btns_group_woman.addButton(self.r_btn_woman_A)
        self.r_btns_group_woman.addButton(self.r_btn_woman_B)

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.r_btn_woman_A, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.r_btn_woman_B, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_add_woman, 1, 2)

    def add_woman(self):
#        if self.ui.self.ui.r_btn_woman_A.isEnabled():
        if self.r_btn_woman_A.isChecked():
            print("A")
        else:
            print("B")
            
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]